# Is there a way to emit event on rendering of component?

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, javascript, lwc-dom

I am wanting to emit an event if I have only 1 search record returned in my search result. This would be by having a `lightning-radio-group` being selected once checking the length of my returned query being equal to 1, this is done by a getter method checking the length and returning the value for the `lightning-radio-group` to be selected. I have tried `connectedCallback()` that had an event be emitted and having a function that would be called in a getter method that would emit the event, but when doing these it breaks the component and does not load. In short terms, I am trying to replicate `selectedSearchResult()` to work on rending of the screen without having to click on the radio button. `searchResultRecords` is a JSON response payload but it is converted to a list from the Apex callout which is bringing in the records for the search result from an outside API endpoint. This is being set in this `child component`. I have an identical function being used when there are multiple results in `searchResultRecords`, this function `selectedSearchResult` however emits an event when a `lightning-radio-group` is clicked on by the user. So if I have 5 results rendered on screen, the user can click result #3 and that will then emit the `data-key` to the parent component. This function `selectedSearchResult` is working and behaves as intended, as this allows the user to select the option they are wanting. I however, would like to save the user a single click by having it emit on default when there is only 1 record available. I have supplied code below to see how this looks.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="custom box">
     <lightning-radio-group name="radioGroup" 
          class="result-select-radio" 
          options={options} 
          value={filterSearchResults} 
          type="radio" 
          data-key={searchResult.Id} 
          onClick={selectedSearchResult}>
     </lightning-radio-group>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
get filterSearchResults(){
     if(this.searchResultRecords.length === 1){
          return 'option1';
     }return '';
}

selectedSearchResult(event){
     let selectedIdValue = event.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-key');
     let searchDetail = {selectedId:selectedIdValue};
     const searchSelection = new CustomEvent('defaultselectedprovider',
          {detail: searchDetail});
     this.dispatchEvent(searchSelection);
}
```

**JS functions I tried and didn't work:**

***attempt #1***

```
get filterSearchResults(){
         if(this.searchResultRecords.length === 1){
              onlySelectedSearchResultEvent()
              return 'option1';
         }return '';
    }

onlySelectedSearchResultEvent(){
         let selectedIdValue = this.template.querySelector.getAttribute('data-key');
         let searchDetail = {selectedId:selectedIdValue};
         const searchSelection = new CustomEvent('defaultselectedprovider',
              {detail: searchDetail});
         this.dispatchEvent(searchSelection);
}
```

***attempt #2***

```
conncedCallback(){
     if(this.searchResultRecords.length ===1){
          this.onlySelectedProviderEvent();
      }
}
onlySelectedSearchResultEvent(){
         let selectedIdValue = this.template.querySelector.getAttribute('data-key');
         let searchDetail = {selectedId:selectedIdValue};
         const searchSelection = new CustomEvent('defaultselectedprovider',
              {detail: searchDetail});
         this.dispatchEvent(searchSelection);
}
```

Comment: What is searchResultRecords? Where is this being set? The timing problem likely has to do with where the data is coming from. In other words, this may be an [X-Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Please [edit] your question to include relevant details so we can help you. If you reply to this comment with `@sfdcfox`, I'll get a notification and I can look at this for you.

Comment: @sfdcfox I added more details to the question above. Hopefully it is more clear of what I am looking for and how everything is setup in the component. I also answered if it is a X-Y problem, it is not in this case. As an identical function is built for when the user clicks on the radio group that has been rendered for each individual search result. Let me know if there is anything else I can do to help clarify and sorry for editing this so late.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution to this was creating a `renderedCallBack()` function to go ahead and call the function for the default value of the options section. This would be by having the function `selectedSearchResult()` be duplicated and have the new duplicated function have a global variable `defaultSelectedId` set for the ID.

**JS:**

```
defaultSelectedId;

castEvent(){
     let searchDetail = {selectedId:defaultSelectedId};
     const searchSelection = new CustomEvent('defaultselectedprovider',
          {detail: searchDetail});
     this.dispatchEvent(searchSelection);
}

renderedCallback(){
     this.castEvent();
}
```